# Telegram API - How to obtain data from a invite link? Chat ID, Image, Title, Desc

Tags: telegram, webhooks

I'm new in APIs.
I'm using Telegram webhooks successfully, but with that webhooks from my bot API I can't get some essential info for me.
I would like to take the chat id, image, title and desc with just a link : t.me/joinchat/example
I know this is possible with messages.checkChatInvite https://core.telegram.org/method/messages.checkChatInvite
But I don't know how to use that type of request, I only know how to use the http requests, I don't even know what type of language is that and what "Layers" mean. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Do you have a solution?